# How to make a game object appear through triggers from 3 different game objects

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unityscript, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am developing an AR app using Unity3D and Vuforia.

I did all the basics of AR and now in the process of completing it.

However, I am currently stuck at the triggers part.

I have 3 flashcards (Number 1, Number 2, Plus). I have put box colliders in each one of them and rigidbodies in Number 1 and Number 2. The Plus card acts as the trigger.

Right now, I am trying to make the game objects in each card disappear when triggered, and a fourth game object will appear when the trigger happens. The fourth game object is the result of the addition (i.e. 1 + 2 = 3).

I have developed the following code. The game objects are triggered according to the tags I have given them. The game objects disappear, but the fourth game object doesn't appear. What have I done wrong here?

```
#pragma strict

var mathplus : GameObject;
var sphere01 : GameObject;
var sphere02 : GameObject;
var result03 : GameObject;

function Start(){
    sphere01.SetActive(true);
    sphere02.SetActive(true);
    mathplus.SetActive(true);
    result03.SetActive(false);
}

function OnTriggerEnter (other : Collider) {
    Debug.Log("Object entered the trigger.");
    if (other.tag == "number01" && other.tag == "number02"){
        mathplus.SetActive(false);
        sphere01.SetActive(false);
        sphere02.SetActive(false);
        result03.SetActive(true);
    }
}

function OnTriggerExit (other : Collider) {
    Debug.Log("Object exited the trigger.");
    mathplus.SetActive(true);
    sphere01.SetActive(true);
    sphere02.SetActive(true);
    result03.SetActive(false);
}
```

The game objects in the Number cards are called "sphere", the game objects in the Plus card is called "mathplus", and the fourth game object is called "result03".

I hope someone can help rectify this problem.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1):

You made a small mistake.

It is because **the fourth card is disabled, so the collider of it is disabled too.**

Your logic is right, what you should do is **invisible the card4, not disable it**

#### Disable Mesh Rendering To Hide A Gameobject

```
      GetComponent(MeshRenderer).enabled = false;
```

It is c# script, sorry, I do not know very about unity js.

You can get more detail from [invisible Gameobject and disable Gameobject](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/7776/how-to-make-an-gameobject-invisible-and-disappeare.html)